# [Flutter Error ]-Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'XFile' Error whe trying to send an image to the server

Tags: flutter, http, dart, multipart

So I'm trying to use the image picker and select an image from the gallery and send it to the server using a REST API.Image image picked from the gallery is in the XFILE format.

BLOC function to send the image to the server:

```dart
  Future<void> _onPaymentSlipSubmitEvent(
      PaymentSlipSubmitEvent event, Emitter<BankTransferScreenState> emit) async {
    try {
      final ApiResponse apiResponse = await courseRepo.sendBankSlip(BankSlipRequest(courseId: state.courseId,slip:event.slip,paidAmount:state.amount));
      if (apiResponse.status) {
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      snackBarBloc.add(OpenSnackBar(e.toString()));
     }
    }
```

Repository function:

```dart
    Future<ApiResponse> sendBankSlip(BankSlipRequest bankSlipRequest) async {
    final ApiResponse apiResponse = await restServiceProvider.post("/courses/create-payment", bankSlipRequest.toJson());
    return apiResponse;
    }
```

BankSlipRequest class:

```dart
    import 'package:care_giver_app/models/api_request.dart';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

    class BankSlipRequest extends ApiRequest{
      String courseId="";
      XFile? slip;
      String paidAmount="";

      BankSlipRequest({required this.courseId,required this.slip,required this.paidAmount});

       BankSlipRequest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
         courseId = json['course_Id'];
         slip = json['proof_image'];
         paidAmount = json['paid_amount'];
       }

       Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "course_Id": courseId,
        "proof_image": slip,
        "paid_amount": paidAmount,
        };
       }
```

POST method in my RestServiceProvider class to send the file to the server:

```dart
Future<ApiResponse> post(String url, dynamic body) async {
    logger.i('Api Post, url $_url$url');
    logger.i('Api Post, data ${body.toString()}');
    ApiResponse apiResponse;
    try {
      final response =
          await http.post(Uri.parse(_url + url), body: body, headers: _headers);
      apiResponse = _returnResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      logger.e('No net');
      throw FetchDataException('No Internet connection');
    }
    return apiResponse;
    }
```

when I try to send the file to the serve I get this error

```
    Error: Unhandled error Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'XFile' 
    occurred in Instance of 'BankTransferScreenBloc'.
```

I'm assuming its something to do with the file format of the image(XFile).

Answer (score 0):

In the file you pick the image, you should access the path of the 8mage which will return the String. Say your variable is selectedImage

```
final XFile? selectedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
if(selectedImage!=null){
   slip = selectedImage.path;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the image not being a multipart file